# systemd configuration for a mono service

Tags: mono, systemd

I can run a mono application as a daemon using mono-service on Fedora 19.

To set some environment variables, I first must execute a script

```
/opt/mono/env.sh
```

I can then run the mono application as a daemon using

```
mono-service -d:/opt/mediabrowser-server/ -m:mediabrowser-server -n:mediabrowser-server /opt/mediabrowser-server/MediaBrowser.Server.Mono.exe -programdata /var/opt/mediabrowser-server/
```

I would like the application to auto-start as a service with a systemd configuration.  My attempts have not been successful

My configuration is

```
[Unit]
Description=Media Browser 3

[Service]
User=smitopher
Group=smitopher
ExecStart=/opt/mono/bin/mono-service -d:/opt/mediabrowser-server/ -m:mediabrowser-server -n:mediabrowser-server /opt/mediabrowser-server/MediaBrowser.Server.Mono.exe -programdata /var/opt/mediabrowser-server/
Type=forking
TimeoutStopSec=20

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The User has the script added to the .bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
. /opt/mono/env.sh
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong or should be doing are solicited.

Answer (score 0):

systemd does not run a user's bash rc. You need to set the environment variables by using the Environment= directive. Alternatively, use a wrapper script, /opt/mono/bin/mono-service-wrapper.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh

. /opt/mono/env.sh

exec /opt/mono/bin/mono-service $@
```

then just change the systemd service to use the wrapper script (keeping the arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Use `EnvironmentFile=` in your systemd unit to load a file containing environment variables.